# iOS: StatusBar appearance error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have first `ViewController` with Portrait orientation and second `ViewController` with landscape orientation. The first `ViewController` have status bar, the second have not.

Then I present second `ViewController` from the first `ViewController`, it presenting with out status bar. Then I dismiss it I go back to first `ViewController` and have my status bar, but the position of the View is incorrect.

View position like screen have not status bar. How can I update it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, try this:

In your landscape VC declare the following:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true];
    // you can also try to hide the status bar with animation:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

In your portraint VC declare the following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:false];
    // you can also try to show the status bar with animation:
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:false withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```